# Is it possible to send event value to child function

Tags: javascript, function, events, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

I am building a confirming pop-up.

```
function addingCoin() {
const table = document.querySelector('.list__table');
const addCancelBtn = document.getElementById('list__popup__cancel');
const addConfirmBtn = document.getElementById('list__popup__confirm');
const addChecker = document.querySelector('.list__popup');

table.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addChecker.classList.toggle('hidden');

    addCancelBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        addChecker.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
    addConfirmBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        addChecker.classList.toggle('hidden');
        const coinAmount = event.target.inputAmount;
    };
```

I want to send the event to child function to make the variable "coinAmount" work properly. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "child function"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do it this way by creating a new function

```
const header = document.querySelector("#__next > div > header");
const headline = document.querySelector("#__next > div > main > main > div > header > h3");

header.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    headline.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handleClick(event);
    });
})

function handleClick (theEvent) {
    console.log(theEvent);
    // Log for the event => PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}
}
```

Hope that this helps you.